# app engine update all sessions for user

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, gae-sessions

In my gae application, a user can do an action (buy something). I need that information stored persistently and available imediately on all requests from all sessions of this user on multiple devices/browsers. I'm using webapp2_extras sessions.
The way I'm thinking of doing this is either:

1) adding the action_happened field to the User model and make it available in the session by adding it to the list in webapp2_extras.auth['user_attributes'] config. But this doesn't work unless the user is logged out on all sessions.

or 2) create a memcache entry (backed by the datastore) for each user like user_id_action_happened and check if it is true or false on each request. This is my preffered method.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No, I think `2)` is your best approach -- the core ideas is to have that entry in the datastore and query it on each request, memcache's just a further (probably worthwhile:-) optimization but doesn't change the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think storing in database and doing a query on each request is the most natural option.

Don't know about your full requirements and specifications, but for keeping the sessions synchronized I think a solution like [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) makes a lot of sense, though it might be overkill in your case.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer! I'll try then to modify my design so as to allow this information only on specific user requests.